# My uwsgi.ini is unable to locate the my application

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, uwsgi, aws-fargate

I am getting this error when I execute this cmd `uwsgi uwsgi.ini`

`--- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---`

Since I'm using `uwsgi.ini` file. where i've specified

```
[uwsgi]
http = 0.0.0.0:3031
module = applicationfolder:app
```

as my project structure is like this

```
|-project
    |-deployment
        |-api
            myapp.ini
    |-applicationfolder
        __init__.py
```

As my application need to run `__init__.py` under `applicationfolder` as it is starting point of my application. I think this is what i need todo but i do not how. after many  tries still getting back same issue. Anyone know how to deal with this?